# How to map Map<String, Entity> with a non-unique value set in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, dictionary, jpa, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to map a `Map<String, Entity>` with a non-unique value set in JPA 2.1. The relationship can be uni-directional for now. There're a trillion explanations how to map a `Map<String, Entity>` with a unique value set, but this question is not about that.

I have a

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Long id;

    [constructors, getter and setter]
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @MapKey(name = "id")
    private Map<String, Entity2> entity2Map = new HashMap<>();
```

and my `persistence.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="richtercloud_jpa-map-with-non-unique-value-set_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

which causes

```
Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2(1l);
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1(2l);
entity1.getEntity2Map().put("a", entity2);
entity1.getEntity2Map().put("b", entity2);
entityManager.persist(entity2);
entityManager.persist(entity1);
```

to fail due to (I desperately tried to switch the output to English, but don't seem to figure it out; the essence is that the two `Entity2` references cause a primary key constraint violation):

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:878)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:721)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ENTITY1_ENTITY2' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL180327114054560' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO ENTITY1_ENTITY2 (entity2Map_ID, Entity1_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="entity2Map" sql="INSERT INTO ENTITY1_ENTITY2 (entity2Map_ID, Entity1_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ENTITY1_ENTITY2' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL180327114054560' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO ENTITY1_ENTITY2 (entity2Map_ID, Entity1_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="entity2Map" sql="INSERT INTO ENTITY1_ENTITY2 (entity2Map_ID, Entity1_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2056)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(StatementQueryMechanism.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping.insertIntoRelationTable(ManyToManyMapping.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping.performDataModificationEvent(ManyToManyMapping.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ENTITY1_ENTITY2' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL180327114054560' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40$1.invoke(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:437)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy341.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'ENTITY1_ENTITY2' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel-Constraint bzw. für einen von 'SQL180327114054560' identifizierten und eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 100 more
```

in a JTA-based Java EE project deployed to Payara 4.1.2.181 with EclipseLink and Apache Derby.

`@MapKeyColumn` is mapping between basic types, e.g. `Map<String, String>`.

I didn't try `@CollectionTable` because it

> Specifies the table that is used for the mapping of collections of basic or embeddable types.

In case I can't figure this out, I might transform the `Map<String, Entity>` into a `Set<WrappingEntity>` where `WrappingEntity` contains an id, the string value and the `Entity2` reference which might even be more efficient, but I'd like to figure this out as well. The approach should generally work since a table with `Entity1`'s id, the string map key and the map `Entity2` value could use `Entity1`'s id and the string map key as primary key.

An SSCCE can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/jpa-map-with-non-unique-value-set.

Comment: What schema do you have? did you let your JPA provider create it? The JPA provider I use creates a PK constraint on the Map table (ENTITY1_ENTITY2 in your case) with the FK column back to ENTITY1, and the KEY, hence value has no such constraint, and it works fine.

Comment: @BillyFrost I have EclipseLink 2.5 generate the schema (I added `persistence.xml` to the question to clarify). Now the big obvious question: which JPA provider did you use to get this working?

Comment: I use DataNucleus JPA. I don't have the `@MapKey` since that is for where you have the map represented by a column in the value table to be the key of the map; I use a join table to represent the map, like this http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_map_join_simple_pc  Is this what you're trying to achieve? because you clearly cant have the key stored in the value if using the value multiple times in a single map

Comment: @BillyFrost You're right. This works with DataNucleus 5.1.4, but why not with EclipseLink 2.5, Hibernate, 5.2? Thank for the investigation and the comment. Would you consider it a bug that it's not working in EclipseLink and Hibernate? Any other possibility to get this working without switching to DataNucleus?

Comment: @crizzis That's a good explanation which I'd accept as an answer, thank you. `@ManyToMany` includes `Entity2.id` in the primary key as well (which complies to your explanation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the JPA 2.1 spec even mentions entities as non-unique values in a to-many association, so that's not really a bug, it's just that the behavior is unspecified (some providers might support such a feature, by chance or by design).

That being said, it makes sense for a unique constraint on `Entity2.id` to exist in a join table for a one-to-many association. I'd try switching to `@ManyToMany` (at your own risk, because... unspecified behaviour)